# Connection problem to MySQL on another machine on LAN

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble connecting to a MySQL database on the other machine on the same network.

```
Could not connect to the specified instance. 
MySQL error number 1130 
Host 'abc' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server        
(Pinging ok time 1-3 ms ttl =128)
```

I've checked out the following:

- TCP/IP enabled
- RegEdit under hlocal machine .... parameters .. maxUserpORT And timedelay..
- Grant all . to 'root'@'Myipaddress'

Answer (score 2):

Isn't grant all to 'root'@'abc' needed in addition to 'root'@'ipaddress of abc'?

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to use the command "flush Privileges;" for the mySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a firewall exception to port 3306 or which ever port MySQL is using, otherwise you firewall will block remote access to port 3306.

You may do this from the MySQL Configuration wizard. Also on the connection wizard, it will ask if the "root" would have remote access. Check the box. That's all.

Comment: If it were a firewall problem, he wouldn't be getting an error message from the server.